# A program that copy my files and paste them in the same locations

Tags: c++

I'm setting up my new project about coping and pasting files, I want to make a program that just copy my desktop files and paste them in the same location but with different name.

I'm Using "filesystem" library for the 'copy' function
I tried like this but this is opening for me a folder in the desktop and just copy my files inside the folder, I don't want a folder to be created.

This is my program, 1 line of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

string desktopdir = "C:\\Users\\roile\\Desktop\\";
string desktopdir2 = "C:\\Users\\roile\\Desktop\\";

int main()
{
    filesystem::copy(desktopdir, desktopdir2);
    return 0;
}
```

The first parameter is a variable that copy the files, and the second is pasting.
How can I make a program like i said, and how can I change the files name ?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to iterate each file in the directory and copy them individually.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Hey Nathan, is there a simple way to do this ? and my program can't know what types of files the user have on his desktop.

Comment: @CodingUniversity Why would you need to know the type of a file to copy it? Copying a file is just copying the bytes it contains, you don't need to know *anything* about what those bytes represent to do that.

Comment: `std::filesystem` will allow iteration and copy. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs)

Comment: @drescherjm But i said in my question that i tried with copy function from filesystem library.

Comment: My point is it has everything you need to accomplish your task. It can help you, iterate, separate out the path parts (filename, directory, extension ...) so you can rename, and it will help you copy.

Comment: Use [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) to split the filename out of the path.

Comment: @drescherjm My program still not working after many tries. Please help me, give me an example so i can continue

Comment: ***Please help me, give me an example so i can continue*** At StackOverflow if you want help with your non working code you need to show the code that you tried. We generally don't just write you a program that meets your specifications. [mcve]

Comment: @drescherjm I still can't make it work, I have only tried to play with this function and switch between 'copy' to 'copy_file' function, but still not working for me, it just not doing anything.